# Get two tooltip bubbles but only want one

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an image (orange circle) that shows a tooltip with a message (covered by red lines in the image):

[image]

However, I only want the black tooltip bubble to appear and not the generic white bubble at the bottom.

I have the following tooltip in my JavaScript at pageLoad:

```
$('#<%=alarmClipsDurationWarning.ClientID%>').tooltip({ 'placement': 'center right', 'title': $('#<%=alarmClipsDurationWarning.ClientID%>').attr('title'), 'delay': 0 });
```

HTML:

```
<i id="alarmClipsDurationWarning" runat="server" class="icon-exclamation-sign icon-large" style="cursor:pointer;color:orange"></i>
```

The `title` will change when a drop down item is changed on the C# side:

```
alarmClipsDurationWarning.Attributes.Add("title", GetAlarmClipsDurationWarningToolTip());
```

`GetAlarmClipsDurationWarningToolTip()` just returns a string based on the drop down change.  I tried doing a remove then add:

```
alarmClipsDurationWarning.Attributes.Remove("title");
alarmClipsDurationWarning.Attributes.Add("title", GetAlarmClipsDurationWarningToolTip());
```

And I tried this too:

```
alarmClipsDurationWarning.Attributes["title"] = GetAlarmClipsDurationWarningToolTip();
```

But none of them give me a single bubble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white bubble is coming from the `title` attribute. Since you can specify exactly what content you want:

```
$('#<%=alarmClipsDurationWarning.ClientID%>').attr('title')
```

Why not use a different attribute?

```
alarmClipsDurationWarning.Attributes.Add("data-tooltip-content", ...
```

---

```
$('#<%=alarmClipsDurationWarning.ClientID%>').attr('data-tooltip-content')
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more?  Why doesn't it work with `title` but when I change it to another attr name? I thought I needed to use `title`.  Also, you should probably mention in your answer I have to change the attr name on both JavaScript and C# sides for it to be a complete answer  :)

Comment: The "white bubble" is a built-in feature of the browser, created when the element has a `title` attribute. If you use an attribute other than `title`, it won't show up.

Comment: But I am using `title` at this point: `'title': $('#<%=alarmClipsDurationWarning.ClientID%>').attr('data-tooltip-content')`?  Is that `title` specifically for the `tooltip` extension and the `title` in the `attr` function specifically for browser?

Comment: `title` in `'title': $('#` is just a property in a javascript object, not an attribute of an element.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `title` attribute for your tooptip.  There appears to be nothing about the tooptip extension that requires it.  Change it to, say, `data-title` where it is set in C# and where it is read by the Tooltip extension.

Comment: +1 for being correct and posted just right after the other answer